# Installing let's encrypt on new delivery TLD

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt

I registered a `.delivery` domain and I want to install let's encrypt ssl certificate but it's not working it gives the following:

```
> sudo certbot --nginx -d dieselfuel.delivery www.dieselfuel.delivery
usage:
  certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...

Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certificate.
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: www.dieselfuel.delivery
```

I usually use this way to generate ssl certificates for `.com` domains

I use `UBUNTU 18.04`

Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an `-d` for **each** domain;

```sh
sudo certbot --nginx -d dieselfuel.delivery -d www.dieselfuel.delivery
```

---

Or, you'll need a **comma-separated** list for a single `-d`;

```sh
sudo certbot --nginx -d dieselfuel.delivery,www.dieselfuel.delivery
```

[Docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/man/certbot.html)

Comment: thanx, I missed the second `-d`